# Slick + PHP + ACF + JQuery slide reveal not working

Tags: php, jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I've set up two Slick sliders with ACF repeater fields, with one slider with the images and the other with the image title, locations and captions. I would like to make the caption slide up from the 'Show caption' toggle and display the caption. I have written a little code to do so and it works in the first instance, but when the next image is shown, the Show Caption slides up and changes to 'Hide Caption' but does not show the caption. Below is what I've tried:

PHP:

```
<div class="slider--container">

    <div class="slider">
        <?php if( have_rows('current_portfolio') ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('current_portfolio') ): the_row(); ?>

                <?php
                    $image = get_sub_field('image');

                    ?>
                    <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center right;" ;></div>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>

<div class="meta-info-container">
    <div class="info">
        <?php if( have_rows('current_portfolio') ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('current_portfolio') ): the_row(); ?>

                <?php

                    $title = get_sub_field('image_title');
                    $location = get_sub_field('location');
            $publication = get_sub_field('publication');
             $caption = get_sub_field('caption');
                    ?>
                    <div>
                        <?php echo $title; ?>
                            <BR>
                            <?php echo $location; ?>
                                <BR>
                                <?php echo $publication; ?>


                                    <div id="caption">
                                        <?php echo $caption; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <BR>
                                    <a href="#" id="toggle">Caption</a>
                    </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>




    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $('a#toggle').click(function () {
        var link = $(this);
        $('#caption').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                link.text('Close Caption');
            } else {
                link.text('Caption');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#caption {
display: none;
color: #000;
}

#toggle {
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

I'm assuming I have to add an individual meta detail as part of this but I've been playing with it for a while and would love to be pointed in the right direction!

Comment: You can't have multiple ids on the same page, there should be only one unique id, so you can either target a class or add a number in front of each "toggle" using a loop counter.

Comment: thanks- however when i change both to class names it doesn't work!

Comment: sorry - my mistake. all working now.

Comment: i'd love to see this in action.  what did you change to fix it?